# Simple navigation through pages spring

Tags: java, spring

I am a Spring beginner and was recently looking at this tutorial
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-annotation-example/

(There's a download link at the bottom of the page and with a quick maven install you should be able to run the project very easily.)

I noticed that when I pressed the submit button on the 1st page and it goes to the 2nd page, the URL stays the same. Now, I modified the 2nd page to have **its own form**. Unfortunately, because the URL is still the same on the 2nd page, Spring picks the controller for the 1st page when I click the 2nd page's submit button.
Why does this happen and how can I override this behavior?

Apologies if I am not being clear enough. Feel free to ask for certain clarification.

Thanks for your time
Regards
Steve

**EDIT : My 2nd page's form looks like this**

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="step2">

    <table width="800" align="center"
        style="border-width: 5px; border-style: solid; border-color: gray;">
        <caption>
            <b>STEP 2</b>
        </caption>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" value="Submit Page 2"
                cssClass="field" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

Comment: How are you specifying the form action in the 2nd form ?Some code samples will help.

Comment: Url is still the same on second page because server is forwarding the request?

Comment: Thanks @indoknight, How do I prevent this behavior? I want the correct URL to be displayed when I navigate to the 2nd page (not the same URL for the first page).

Comment: @StevePaul, what you posted is the JSP content. Can you post the generated html form contect? Alternatively you can use [Redirect View](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-redirectview-example/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the url to be updated when you navigage from Page1 to Page2 with Page2 url. Then use redirect on the server side instead of forward. I'm not how you do in Spring MVC, you may want to check Spring MVC reference manual.